# Retrieve dictionary value jinja

Tags: jquery, python, dictionary, jinja2

I have a python Dictionary that looks like this

```
[{"hat": 91, "d1b": 2, "d1c": 1, "d1d": 5, "d1e": 7, "d1f": 77, "d1e": 999}
{"hat": 1, "d2b": 2, "d2c": 3, "d2d": 4, "d2e": 5, "d2f": 6, "d2e": 7}
{"hat": 1, "d3b": 2, "d3c": 3, "d3d": 4, "d3e": 5, "d3f": 6, "d3e": 7}]
```

And i pass this as a dictionary object (mydict) from python to jinja

What I'm tryrng to do is loop through each dictionary and print out the value of the key i search for. And have that show in a jquery alert box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        {% for i in mydict %}
          {{ loop.index0 }}, {{a,["hat"] }}
               alert( {{ hat }} );
            {% endfor %}
        });
```

When i go to my web page it gives me an error of

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

$(document).ready(function() {


          0, (Undefined, [&#91;hat&#91;])
               alert(  );

          1, (Undefined, [&#1;hat&#1;])
               alert(  );

          2, (Undefined, [&#1;hat&#1;])
               alert(  );

        });
```

Its not being defined, and its not printing an alert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use call like python for dictionary (it's not collection):

```
{% for i in dict %}
    {{ i['hat'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Collections can be accessed as dictionaries, and dictionaries cannot be called as a collection. Any way you need use **i.hat** if this collection or **i['hats']** if it's a collection or a dictionary.

Just try to replace it:

```
alert( {{ hat }} );
```

to:

```
alert( {{ i['hat'] }} );
```

Comment: Sorry, it is a collection, forgot to put it in OP, check the edit.

Comment: I'm glad I could help